# GET Azure Blob using JQuery from a Chrome App

Tags: jquery, cors, google-chrome-app, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to do a simple GET request from a Chrome App that I'm developing to a blob on my Azure Storage using the following jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'x-ms-range': 'bytes=' + from + '-' + to,
            'x-ms-version': version,
            'x-ms-client-request-id': guid()
        },
        url: 'https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-id/blob-id?sv=2015-07-08&sr=b&sig=signature&st=2016-08-24T08%3A58%3A30Z&se=2016-08-24T09%3A28%3A30Z&sp=rl&api-version=2015-07-08&',
        type: "GET",
    }).done(function (data) {
    }).fail(function (error) {
});
```

When I try, I get the following errors:

> OPTIONS https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-id/blob-id?sv=2015-07-08&sr=b&sig=signature&st=2016-08-24T08%3A58%3A30Z&se=2016-08-24T09%3A28%3A30Z&sp=rl
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-id/blob-id?sv=2015-07-08&sr=b&sig=signature&st=2016-08-24T08%3A58%3A30Z&se=2016-08-24T09%3A28%3A30Z&sp=rl. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://blablabla' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Please help! I tried lots of CORS options but none worked for me.
I really want to keep it a simple ajax request, and avoid using custom libraries for that request.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried [enabling CORS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx) via the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://docbetaeustorage.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
          'x-ms-date': new Date(),
          'x-ms-version': '2013-08-15',
          'Authorization': 'SharedKey'
        },
        type: "PUT",
        data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><StorageServiceProperties><Cors><CorsRule><AllowedOrigins>' + THIS_URL + '</AllowedOrigins><AllowedMethods>GET,PUT</AllowedMethods><MaxAgeInSeconds>500</MaxAgeInSeconds><ExposedHeaders>x-ms-*</ExposedHeaders><AllowedHeaders>x-ms-*</AllowedHeaders></CorsRule></Cors></StorageServiceProperties>'
    }).done(function (data) {
    }).fail(function (error) {
});
```

and now I get the preflight error on this request...

Comment: Just for testing purpose, could you try setting the AllowedOrigins , ExposedHeaders and AllowedHeaders as * ?

Comment: It doesn't matter... It still falls on preflight.

Comment: couple of silly doubts - as per documentation,  'x-ms-date' should be UTC - would that be a problem? And are you sure about the x-ms-version? The current version of the Azure storage services is 2015-12-11

Comment: Doesn't work with UTC either and that's the version according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx . I don't think that the put request is even processed... It's stuck on the OPTIONS request that is automatically generated...

Comment: OPTIONS pre flight request will be generated for PUT and DELETE cross domain requests as well as for other verbs in case there are custom headers and the content type is not within the allowed types. So preflight shouldnt be a problem if you are authenticated fine in that request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to use any custom libraries for this. All you have to need is enable CORS in your Blob storage.

You can find the details here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors/

*below code will be relevant only for C# developers. There are REST api to enable CORS in azure*

And this is how I enabled CORS via C# code in my blob account:

```
public void EnableCors(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, CorsRequest corsRequest, IRequestOptions requestOptions=null, OperationContext operationContext = null)
        {
            var serviceTypeClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();

            // Nullifying un-needed properties so that we don't 
            // override the existing ones 
            serviceProperties.HourMetrics = null;
            serviceProperties.MinuteMetrics = null;
            serviceProperties.Logging = null;


            serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
            {
                AllowedHeaders = corsRequest.AllowedHeaders,
                ExposedHeaders = corsRequest.ExposedHeaders,
                AllowedMethods = corsRequest.AllowedMethods,
                AllowedOrigins = corsRequest.AllowedOrigins,
                MaxAgeInSeconds = corsRequest.PreFlightRequestAgeInMins * 60,
            });
            serviceTypeClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties, requestOptions as BlobRequestOptions, operationContext);
        }
```

where storageAccount - your storage account

corsRequest - just the required values I read it from config file

*I kept requestOptions and operationContext as null*

Comment: @shlatchz - Me too.. The above code is to enable cors via C#.

Comment: But I clearly stated that I'm using javascript JQuery.
I tried making the put request described in the url https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx , and now  I get the preflight error on that request.

Comment: @Developer...in a razor web application you run this in Startup?

Comment: @Developer...and what library is the CorsRequest class from?

Comment: @dinotom - I had a custom wrapper client for Blob (to make my code agnostic of Azure Blob storage, local file storage and AWS S3) and I did this in the static constructor. Btw, you can now set the cors via Azure Portal itself

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it working... I didn't know that the CORS setup was a one-time-thing.

I took the storage account's connection key from azure portal:

[image: Connection String from Portal]

and I just ran the following code once in C#:

```
namespace EnableCorsInAzure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connString = "--MY-CONNECTION-STRING-FROM-AZURE-PORTAL--";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            ServiceProperties serviceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();
            serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
            serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
            {
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Delete,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600,
            });
            blobClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        }
    }
}
```

while including `WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget.

Comment: aint this we discussed at the beginning?

Comment: As I said, I didn't know that I only had to do it once. I thought that it has to be done before each request.